# Cannot edit Magento order or send the email from “sales - orders” inside admin

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

We updated to `magento 1.9.2.1` but now we can't edit any order or send the email from the order itself inside "sales - orders"; what could be the reason? CronJobs are working properly.
When I click "edit order" or "send email" inside Firefox error console I read:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Have you check log or exception ?

Comment: what should I look for especially?

Comment: @LaurenFrida check var/log/system.log file and var/log/exception.log file

Comment: yes, I opened them, there are too many logs inside; what should I search for exactly?

Comment: if I click on edit or send the email I get this error inside firefox error console: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list